# Splitting a string intelligently in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, string

I want to break a string into chunks of 200 characters or smaller, but breaking at the spaces. How can I do this in VB.net? For example:

`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ut dui et sapien ultricies laoreet. Duis eleifend ante et tortor adipiscing tincidunt. Nulla sagittis purus sit amet mauris convallis auctor cursus orci volutpat. Nam id massa eu purus congue adipiscing. Nam a ligula in justo euismod fermentum eget et risus. Sed magna lectus, adipiscing in accumsan eu, porttitor id mauris. Suspendisse eros velit, ullamcorper elementum interdum et, tempor sed velit. Curabitur et velit purus, ut amet.`

should be the starting string. Following this example, what I'm trying to extract is:

`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ut dui et sapien ultricies laoreet. Duis eleifend ante et tortor adipiscing tincidunt. Nulla sagittis purus sit amet mauris convallis`

and

`auctor cursus orci volutpat. Nam id massa eu purus congue adipiscing. Nam a ligula in justo euismod fermentum eget et risus. Sed magna lectus, adipiscing in accumsan eu, porttitor id mauris.`

and

`Suspendisse eros velit, ullamcorper elementum interdum et, tempor sed velit. Curabitur et velit purus, ut amet.`

assuming no whitespace is left on the ends. How can I achieve this in vb.net?

Comment: You can do a count if you like, the first chunk is 197 (less than 200), the second is 190 (less than 200), and the final is 111, which is also less than 200.

Comment: With all due respect, the accepted answer loops 76 times and performs 74 string concatenations with the given text. Regular expressions are designed for pattern matching and are a perfect fit for this case. Please have a look at my solution, which uses 3 loops and no string concatenation. It will also work when the text is separated by hyphens, tabs, carriage returns, or other whitespace, whereas the accepted answer works only with spaces.

Comment: Spaces are the only separations I'll be dealing with and looping is no issue, script efficiency is no object here. It's for personal use only and doesn't need to work immediately when the function is called, even 3-5 seconds of loops would be find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the function:

```
Private Function split(ByVal textToSplit As String, ByVal charCount As Integer) As System.Collections.Queue

    Dim returnQueue As New System.Collections.Queue

    Dim words As String() = textToSplit.Split(" ".ToCharArray)

    Dim currentChunk As String = ""

    For index As Integer = 0 To words.GetUpperBound(0)

        Dim currentWord As String = words(index)

        If currentChunk.Length + currentWord.Length <= charCount Then
            'The phrase is still short enough
            currentChunk += " " & currentWord
        Else
            'The phrase would be too long
            'Add the chunk to the list
            returnQueue.Enqueue(currentChunk)
            'Start a new chunk
            currentChunk = currentWord
        End If

    Next index

    'Reached the end. Add the last chunk to the list
    returnQueue.Enqueue(currentChunk)

    Return returnQueue

End Function
```

Call it like this:

```
    Dim s As String = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ut dui et sapien ultricies laoreet. Duis eleifend ante et tortor adipiscing tincidunt. Nulla sagittis purus sit amet mauris convallis auctor cursus orci volutpat. Nam id massa eu purus congue adipiscing. Nam a ligula in justo euismod fermentum eget et risus. Sed magna lectus, adipiscing in accumsan eu, porttitor id mauris. Suspendisse eros velit, ullamcorper elementum interdum et, tempor sed velit. Curabitur et velit purus, ut amet."

    For Each chunk As String In split(s, 200)
        Debug.WriteLine(chunk)
    Next
```

Comment: Have a look at regular expressions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expressions They'll fundamentally change the way anyone works with strings. To match the given condition: `^.{0,200}\b` That's it -- "match any character from the start of the string, up to 200, but must end at a word break." In .NET, it is in `System.Text.RegularExpressions`

Answer (score 3):

This *screams* for a regular expression.

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

…

Function Split(ByVal source As String, ByVal chunkMaxLength As Integer) As IEnumerable(Of String)
    Dim index = 0
    Dim maxIndex = source.Length - 1
    Dim src = source
    Dim results As New List(Of String)

    Do While index < maxIndex
        src = source.Substring(index)
        Dim match = Regex.Match(src, "^.{0," & chunkMaxLength & "}\b").ToString()
        results.Add(match)
        index = index + match.Length
    Loop

    Return results

End Function
```

Comment: Looking at this code it works great but if say I am looking for chunk of 5 and the first word is 10 characters long it returns nothing. I understand why but wondering if there is a way around this?